# useNavigate hook with multiple choices?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-hooks

this is my button component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { KeyboardArrowLeft } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./Buttons.css";

export const BackButton = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => navigate(-1)}
      className="back-button"
      size="large"
      startIcon={<KeyboardArrowLeft />}
    />
  );
};
```

It is currently used in every route that I have. In a few routes I want the button to navigate back to -2 pages (but I want -1 do be default), do I rewrite the code in the onClick event or how do I make this possible?

Comment: Have you considered passing the number of pages as a prop to your `BackButton` component? Does that work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a scenario where previous page is not available. How to identify the history length?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a prop with a default value of `1`, then use that prop when you call `navigate()`:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const BackButton = ({navigateTo = 1}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => navigate(-navigateTo)}
      className="back-button"
      size="large"
      startIcon={<KeyboardArrowLeft />}
    />
  );
};

BackButton.propTypes = {
  navigateTo: PropTypes.number
};

export BackButton;
```

The above uses destructuring assignment with a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to set the `navigateTo` value to `1` if it isn't specified.

When you use your `BackButton` component, you can pass through the `navigateTo` amount:

```js
<BackButton navigateTo={2} />
```

If you don't specify the `navigateTo` prop then it'll go back 1 by default

```js
<BackButton />
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but got 'navigateTo' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types.

Comment: Tried importing PropTypes but not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: @thegreenedition seems like your eslint is complaining about a prop-types definition. I've updated my example above to show how you can add propType

Comment: fixed it by adding:
BackButton.propTypes = {
  navigateTo: PropTypes.number,
};

BackButton.defaultProps = {
  navigateTo: -1,
};

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get location with `useLocation` hook and use it in your `onClick`.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const BackButton = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => (location.pathname === "x" ? navigate(-2) : navigate(-1))}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).